# horizontal stacked bar chart with a single series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My simple Dataframe produces a plot with 4 single, horizontal bars, rather than one stacked horizontal bar. I've tried transposing it etc - without success. I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong - but I can't work it out. Help much appreciated!

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake_data = [['dogs',12],['cats',8],['fish',22],['bird',8]]
myDF = pd.DataFrame(fake_data)
myDF.columns = ['animals','count']

myDF.plot.barh(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create one row `DataFrame` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
myDF.set_index('animals')['count'].to_frame().T.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```